# What happens when the buffer pool size is insufficient in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, database-tuning, performance-tuning, query-performance

Let us assume I run a query for a table whose size is very huge. My buffer pool size is as low as possible. What happens now? whether I will get an error regarding the insufficient space in buffer pool or will mysql fetch the data from the disk ? 
Just curious to know the behaviour of mysql in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If MySQL properly started and InnoDB initialized with the configured buffer pool size then there is no reason for any error (barring some bug of course). The *buffer* pool is just that - a memory area used to buffer your IO. When there is not enough of it to keep *all* the *active data*, the server just reads them from disk.

If you had for example 100GB table then many servers won't have enough RAM to contain it and still you may execute a query running *full table scan*.

The performance will be worse (probably substantially, 1-2 orders of magnitude or more) than in case there were enough memory.